# How to give id to label if the field is added by plugin in wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have added a custom field by using plugin in wordpress but now I want to use a jQuery to show/hide that custom field. I am able to hide the field because I know the id of that field but I also want to hide the label of that field but I dont know the id of that label. Please help me.

Comment: html structure of the output first... we might get a better solution with that...

Answer (score 0):

you know the id of the field so just use the following if you have the html structure like

```
<label id="customlabel">....</label>
<input type="text" id="customtext" />


$("#customtext").prev().find('#customlabel').hide();
```

Comment: if you already have the `id` calling it like `$("#customtext")` and `$('#customlabel')` is the best option... no need for `find` or `prev`

Comment: i dont know the id of label.

Comment: thanks for the reply.but in the form there is only label like <label>, i can not edit this because it is in plugin file and dynamicaly created.

Comment: use like this `$("#customtext").prev().find('label').hide();`